# Problema RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un problema con un RecyclerView, es este error:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

segun yo lo estoy haciendo bien... aca el codigo:

Actividad:

```
package com.app.app;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.millennium.millennium.adaptadores.IncentivosAdapter;
import com.millennium.millennium.fragments.MenuFragment;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class IncentivosActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MenuFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    RecyclerView rv;
    Fragment menu;
    IncentivosAdapter iAdapter;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_incentivos);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("configs",MODE_PRIVATE);


        menu = new MenuFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menuFragment,menu).commit();




        String IdApp = sharedPreferences.getString("IdApp","");
        final String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token","");
        String address = getResources().getString(R.string.address);
        final String api = getResources().getString(R.string.apiKey);

        String url = address+"incentivos/"+IdApp+"/list/";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                    JSONArray millenium = obj.getJSONArray("millenium");
                    JSONObject items = (JSONObject) millenium.get(0);
                    JSONArray datos = items.getJSONArray("datos");


                    rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
                    rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2));
                    iAdapter = new IncentivosAdapter(datos);
                    rv.setAdapter(iAdapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("token",token);
                params.put("api",api);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

y este es el adaptador:

```
package com.app.app.adaptadores;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.millennium.millennium.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class IncentivosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IncentivosAdapter.ViewHolderDatos> {


    JSONArray datos;

    public IncentivosAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        this.datos = jsonArray;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_incentivos,null,false);
        return new ViewHolderDatos(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {
        try {
            holder.asignarTitulos(datos.get(position));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datos.length();
    }

    public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView titulo;
        public ViewHolderDatos(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        }

        public void asignarTitulos(Object obj) {
            JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) obj;
            try {
                String tituloactual = temp.getString("name_incentivo");
                titulo.setText(tituloactual);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

lo que trato de hacer es dinamicamente conectarme mediante Volley a una url para obtener un JSON, le envio un JSONArray al adaptador para luego en los titulos de los "Incentivos" agregarle estos titulos mediante la sintaxys que aplico en el Adaptador, espero puedan ayudarme, saludos.

lo que trato de hacer es dinamicamente conectarme mediante Volley a una url para obtener un JSON, le envio un JSONArray al adaptador para luego en los titulos de los "Incentivos" agregarle estos titulos mediante la sintaxys que aplico en el Adaptador, espero puedan ayudarme, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se produce al setear el adapter en el `onResponse`. Deberias setear el `adapter` en el `onCreate`. Entiendo que lo haces asi porque usas los datos recibidos en para crear el adapter. Lo que deberias hacer es setear el adapter con un array vacio y luego agregarle los datos dentro del `onResponse` y perdile que actualice los datos.

Primero seteamos el recycler en el onCreate para que no pinche nada.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_incentivos);

  rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
  rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2));
  iAdapter = new IncentivosAdapter();
  rv.setAdapter(iAdapter);
  ...
```

Despues actualizamos el adapter con los datos obtenidos desde el json

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(String response) {
   try {
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
     JSONArray millenium = obj.getJSONArray("millenium");
     JSONObject items = (JSONObject) millenium.get(0);
     JSONArray datos = items.getJSONArray("datos");

     iAdapter.updateDatos(datos)
   } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

Por ultimo para que todo esto ande hay que modificar tu adapter:

```
Actualizo el adapter
public updateDatos(JSONArray jsonArray) {
  datos = jsonArray
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datos == null ? 0 : datos.length(); //Si aun no hay datos devuelve 0 y evita el nullpointer
}
```

Eso deberia bastar para que todo funcione.

Comment: efectivamente ya no me da el error, pero ahora sigue sin mostrarme los datos, sigo buscando solucion de lo contrario tendre que hacer otra pregunta, muchisimas gracias.

Comment: bien! seguramente estas teniendo problemas con los datos que te llegan, debugea y fijate si no cae por algun try catch o si efectivamente el JSONArray tiene datos dentro

Comment: si de echo, en el adaptador imprimo por el Logcat los name_incentivo y si me los imprime bien, solo que no imprime las vistas o los layouts... es raro :/

Comment: Si los datos estan el problema probablemente se deba a como esta armado el item_incentivos, crea otra pregunta con el contenido de ese xml y el adapter, tambien te ayudaria harcodear los datos para asegurarte que ese no es el problema.

Comment: ya lo solucione habia una propiedad en xml del recycler view que me estaba afectando, muchas gracias.